# How do I use Castle Windsor a different assembly from mvc web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I'm stuck. I want to configure Castle Windsor in a different class library and I configured, build is fine, no error, ok... But I get an exception at run time.

> Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException: No component for supporting the service App.Web.UI.Controllers.HomeController was found

When I get the configure file back to the same assembly (App.Web.UI), I don't get any exception at run time, work is fine.

I tried many ways, but I could not. Is there another bind method except FromThisAssembly? Or Solution?

Castle Windsor configuration is here:

```
namespace App.Infrastructure.Configurations
{
    public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private readonly IKernel _kernel;

        public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
        {
            _kernel = kernel;
        }

        public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
        {
            _kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller);
        }

        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            if (controllerType == null)
            {
                throw new HttpException(404, string.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found.", requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
            }

            return (IController)_kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
        }
    }

    public class ControllersInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IController>().Unless(x => x.Name == "BaseController").LifestyleTransient());
        }
    }

    public class ServiceInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(
                Component.For(typeof (IRepository<>)).ImplementedBy(typeof (Repository<>)).LifestyleTransient(),
                Component.For<IUserService>().ImplementedBy<UserService>().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
                Component.For<IFormsAuthenticationService>().ImplementedBy<FormsAuthenticationService>().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
                Component.For<ILoggingService>().ImplementedBy<LoggingService>().LifestyleTransient(),
                Component.For<IFeedbackService>().ImplementedBy<FeedbackService>().LifestylePerWebRequest()
                ); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  As written, your question is difficult to understand.  Is it possible for you to have a colleague who is a native English speaker review this with you?

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the `Classes.FromThisAssembly()` references the assembly containing your Windsor stuff -- not your web application.  Try telling Windsor to register components from a specific assembly.  This should work:

```
Classes.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly())
```

The entry assembly should be the AppDomain running your MVC code.